# Odoo 11 CE depends on the module: res. But this module is not available in your system

Tags: odoo-11

I'm currently using Odoo 11 CE and developing an app that would add some fields to res.partner. After looking at all the different samples out there I can't figure out why I get this error when upgrading:

> You try to upgrade the module training_center that depends on the
>   module: res. But this module is not available in your system.

In my manifest file I've got the following:
**manifest**.py

```
'name': 'Training Center',
'author': 'Matt',
'website': 'tbd',
'depends': ['base','board', 'document', 'hr', 'web', 'website',
            ],
```

In my models directory I've got the following:
**init**.py
`from . import res_partner`

In my res_partner.py file I've got the following:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

class TC_ResPartner(models.Model):
    """Adds wechat field becomes a stored function field."""
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    wechat_id = fields.Char(
        "Wechat User ID",
        index=True,
        store=True
    )
```

When I go to upgrade in the UI via the APPS/Upgrade button, I get the following error:

> You try to upgrade the module training_center that depends
>   on the module: res. But this module is not available in your system.

When I look in the server log, I see the following worth noting:

```
2018-12-08 16:12:03,313 27437 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.module.module: ALLOW access to module.button_immediate_upgrade on ['training_center'] to user m****@gmail.com #7 via 127.0.0.1 
2018-12-08 16:12:03,313 27437 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.module.module: ALLOW access to module.button_upgrade on ['training_center'] to user m****@gmail.com #7 via 127.0.0.1 
2018-12-08 16:12:03,313 27437 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.module.module: ALLOW access to module.update_list on ['training_center'] to user m****@gmail.com #7 via 127.0.0.1
```

I've not had any permission issues with upgrading until I tried inheriting res.partner.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same issue. You could try adding `res` to `depends` in `__manifest__.py` and restarting the server with `-u all` (which will take a while to rebuild the models from the qweb xml's), and then removing `res` again and repeating